# Why is routing calling HomeController Index when it should be mapped to different controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want the url https://localhost:44354/Bills to call the Index action in the BillsController.cs. Instead, it is calling the Index action from HomeController.cs. If I use https://localhost:44354/Bills/Bills it does call the BillsController's Index action.

The way I understand it, Bills should map to the controller and it should default to Index without a second parameter in the URL. To test, I tried https://localhost:44354/Bills/Index which give a 404. Can someone explain this behavior? It seems to not be behaving correctly.

The routing in my Startup.cs file:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

BillsController:

```
public class BillsController : Controller
    {    
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

My folder structure:

[image]

Comment: Your default route is mapping to `Home` controller, not `Bills` controller

Comment: When you call this: "https://localhost:44354/Bills" it is trying to find a method called "Bills()" into your HomeController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@NickOban, I tried creating a new MCV project and added a bills controller. I then added the Bills repository and added a index.cshtml
[image]

And the pathing worked for me. However, it seems that you might have implemented a prefix at some point with the name "Bills", which would cause the phenomenon you are experiencing.

Ensure you have no prefixes anywhere in your code. The MVC app should automatically fix any prefixes. Additionally try `https://localhost:44354/Bills/Index.cshtml` instead of simply Index ~ because then the MVC is expexting that Index is a Folder.

Comment: `However, it seems that you might have implemented a prefix at some point with the name "Bills", which would cause the phenomenon you are experiencing.` Agreed.

Comment: @Cornelis This does seem most likely. I did create another project and it worked like you'd expect. Strangely, the URL `https://localhost:44354/Bills/Index.cshtml` gives a 404. Not sure where to look for prefixes, my launchSettings.json looks pretty standard, just the base url and port. I also cleared out all the built files in my project and rebuild. No change. Additional thought would be appreciated.

Comment: I think I found the issue. I had gone into the project properties and changed the App URL to https://localhost:44354/Bills. I had subsequently changed it back, but the setting must have stuck. I created a new project and imported all my code. Things work well now. Thanks for all the feedback!